# LED strip matrix for FFT with Python and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raspberry-pi, led

I'm stuck with Python and a LED strip. The LED strip, which has the WS2801 chip and is addressable via SPI, has been arranged as a matrix like this:

```
     ----      ----      ----      ----
140 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 15
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
155 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 0
          ----      ----      ----
```

Each dash represents one LED (one pixel). There are 16 pixels in a column, making up 8 rows.

Numbering starts from bottom right. So the right most column starts with index 0 and ends with index 15. The four pixels between the rows will not be lighted. So the second most right column goes from the top with index 20 down to the bottom with index 35.
The left most column ranges from 140 at the top to 155 at the bottom.

What I want to do is visualize a song's spectrum while it's played. The lower frequencies should be displayed in the left columns, the higher frequencies in the right columns.

My code is based on PixelPi (https://github.com/scottjgibson/PixelPi). I'm leaving out the part with the FFT, because that part is not the problem.

```
# Each pixel consumes 3 bytes
PIXEL_SIZE = 3 

# Lots of colors
BLACK = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00')
AQUA = bytearray(b'\x00\xff\xff')
AQUAMARINE = bytearray(b'\x7f\xff\xd4')

def filter_pixel(input_pixel, brightness):
    output_pixel = bytearray(PIXEL_SIZE)

    input_pixel[0] = int(brightness * input_pixel[0])
    input_pixel[1] = int(brightness * input_pixel[1])
    input_pixel[2] = int(brightness * input_pixel[2])

    output_pixel[0] = gamma[input_pixel[0]]
    output_pixel[1] = gamma[input_pixel[1]]
    output_pixel[2] = gamma[input_pixel[2]]
    return output_pixel

# Initialize LED strip matrix
height  = 16
base    = [155, 120, 115, 80, 75, 40, 35, 0]
# Do the indexes of this column go from bottom to top?
up      = [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
color   = [NAVY, RED, MAROON, DARKBLUE, DARKCYAN, PALEGREEN, YELLOWGREEN, YELLOW]

# Output matrix, filled with black pixels
empty_output = bytearray(args.num_leds * PIXEL_SIZE + 3)
for led in range(args.num_leds):
    empty_output[led * PIXEL_SIZE:] = filter_pixel(BLACK, 1)

current_color = bytearray(PIXEL_SIZE)
corrected_color = bytearray(PIXEL_SIZE)

while True: # (Actually while song is playing)

    # Returns an array of length 8 with values between 0 and 4095
    matrix = calculate_levels(matrix, weighting, data, CHUNK_SIZE, sample_rate)

    # Copy the matrix with only black pixels. Copying seems to be faster than resetting all not needed pixels to black
    pixel_output[:] = empty_output


    for col in range(len(base)):
        current_color[:] = color[col][:]
            # Do some gamma correction
        corrected_color[:] = filter_pixel(current_color[:], 1)

            # Each column is 16 pixels high. The maximum value of the FFT to be returned for each column is 4095. 4096 / 256 = 16
        lighted_height = round(matrix[col]/float(1 << 8), 2)

        for row in range(max(16, int(lighted_height) + 1)):
            pixel_index = base[col] + row if up[col] == True else base[col] - row
            pixel_index = pixel_index * PIXEL_SIZE

            if (row < int(lighted_height)):
                # Pixel's brightness in 100%
                pixel_output[pixel_index:] = corrected_color[:]
            elif (row <= int(lighted_height) and row + 1 > int(lighted_height)):
                # Pixel's brightness is between 0 and 1
                pixel_output[pixel_index:] = filter_pixel(current_color[:], lighted_height - int(lighted_height))

            #print "[col:", col, ", row:", row, "] : ", pixel_index, "lighted_height:", lighted_height, "int(lighted_height)", int(lighted_height), "lighted:", lighted

            # As I uncomment these two lines, at least all pixels on the other columns are displayed.
            #spidev.write(pixel_output)
            #spidev.flush()

    spidev.write(pixel_output)
    spidev.flush()
```

The problem is that this code only lights the right most column (0 to 15). All other columns seem to be black.

When I put the `spidev.write(pixel_output)` and `spidev.flush()` in the col loop such that the pixel_output is written for each column, at least some lights in the other columns light up. However, they're somehow showing up pretty randomly, and the sound is not smooth any more.

By the way, the LED strip is doing fine with the PixelPi examples like fading and chasing.
May this due to some properties of the WS2801 chip which I don't know? Or didn't I calculate the pixel_output matrix correctly?

**Update**: One more strange thing:

```
i = 0
x = 0
while x < 160:
    if i != 0 and i % 16 == 0:
    x = x + 4

    pixel_index = x * PIXEL_SIZE
    pixel_output[pixel_index:] = filter_pixel(WHITE, 1)

    i = i + 1
    x = x + 1

    print "i, x", i, x

    time.sleep(0.1)
    spidev.write(pixel_output)
    spidev.flush()
```

This should actually light up pixel 0 to the last and leave out 4 pixels after 16 executions of the loop. However, it doesn't leave out a pixel and thus stops before the last pixel is reached.

Comment: You need to take a step back and simplify your test case. Get rid of the dependency on the music files and just generate a test pattern with  known values. You'll find your bug that way.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
pixel_output[pixel_index:] = filter_pixel(WHITE, 1)
```

copies not only 3 array elements as I had expected. It copies the values returned by filter_pixel from pixel_index all over the buffer to the end.

Setting an upper limit for copying solved my problem.

```
pixel_output[pixel_index:(pixel_index + PIXEL_SIZE)] = filter_pixel(WHITE, 1)
```